# get maven clean install to work like maven clean + maven install

Tags: java, maven

I have the following project hierarchy:

```
app
|-module1
| |-pom.xml
|-module2
| |-pom.xml
|-pom.xml
```

Module1 and module2 both copies files to the same target directory, so im using the app's pom.xml to clear that directory. My problem is, the execution order right now is module1[clean], module1[install], module2[clean], module2[install], app[clean], app[install], so everything module1 and module2 puts into that directory will be deleted.

I would like to get it to execute all clean first, then all install, even when i run mvn clean install. Or if there is another way to execute app[clean] before module1[install] and module2[install], that would work too.

**EDIT**

I ended up making a separate module (Netbeans POM projekt) for cleaning alone. Not the sollution i was hoping for, but it works for now.

Comment: How about using "mvn clean && mvn install". If you don't actually need maven to do it in single maven execution I think it's a way to go.

Comment: this will be an open source project, and i dont want to break the functionality of the "Clean and Build" button of the IDE

Comment: If you have really the case that Module1 and Module2 copy files into the same target directory there is really something wrong. Apart from that the order of the execution is defined by Maven as you described Module (clean, install) so you can't change this. If this is an open source project can you give a reference?

Comment: I belive maven being a build tool should be used to create the desired file hierarchy for the distribution version of the porject (ex. copy all dependencies to a single lib folder, move licensies/readmes to root folder, etc.), instead of using a shell script like many projects do. The source code is not in a state where i can share it yet.

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem here is that you're trying to make Maven do something that sort-of contradicts Maven's multi-module "conventions", as well as conflicting with Maven's "understanding" of a "target directory". There is a reason why Maven's reactor is operating the way that it does, and it is to preserve the Maven "spirit" (or "convention") of how modules are structured in a multi-module build.

In Maven, the `target` directory is supposed to belong only to one project: each project has its own `target` directory. In your scenario, there should really be a different `target` directory for `app`, `module1` and `module2`.

I suppose your best bet, in order to both achieve your objective *and* keep your build process flexible, is to:

1. Have `module1` output its own JAR into its own `target` directory (`module1/target`).
2. Have `module2` output its own JAR into its own `target` directory (`module2/target`).
3. Add a plugin to `app` (the parent module) that will collect whatever it needs from `module1/target` and `module2/target` into `app/target`, and do whatever processing on those artifacts.